# Why can't you use the word "me" before a proper noun?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, coordinating-conjunctions

As per the title, I don't understand why it is grammatically incorrect to say "me and John went to the park" as opposed to "John and I went to the park." Is any help on this available?

Comment: It's not grammatically incorrect. It's perfectly common in all varieties of English and has been so for well over a century. The logic behind calling it ungrammatical is that you should be able to break up and simplify a conjoined noun phrase (= remove the “and x” or “x and” part) and still be left with a grammatical sentence, which is not the case here: removing “and John” yields “*me went to the park”, which is ungrammatical. There is good evidence, however, that conjoined noun phrases in current English function differently to simple ones, and this ‘test’ is not valid.

Comment: You wouldn't (I hope) say "Me went to the park."  Why would you say "Me and John went to the park"?

Comment: Similarly when showing someone a photo and saying "That's me and John in the park." Right or wrong, it's what you hear everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

It is often considered bad form to put yourself first in such a statement, so rather than "me and John" it should be "John and me". In this case the options are

"John and me went to the park" or "John and I went to the park", following which the previous reply is still applicable.